# How to remove the single dot before each chapter in the TOC and make it smaller?

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I want to remove the single dot as circled in the picture. Using the `thesis` class, the single dot appears and and the toc size becomes bigger. Changing to the `report` class, the dot disappears and the toc size becomes normal. I need to use the `thesis` class to comply with the requirements set by my university.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{thesis}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}
\usepackage{chngcntr}%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}%
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=4cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{rom}
\input{tex/title}\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}
\addtocounter{rom}{1}\setcounter{page}{2}~
\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\setcounter{page}{3}

\tableofcontents

\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}~
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{tex/introduction}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Without knowing what code was used to generate the table of contents, it's well nigh impossible to offer a diagnosis, let along propose a cure. Please provide a minimal working example that gives rise to the issue you're looking to fix.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @Mico i've edit my question

Comment: There are lots and lots of LaTeX documents class files called `thesis` out there on the 'net. Which one would you be using? Is the document class file available online? Your code isn't compilable by others since we don't have access to the files `tex/title.tex` and `tex/introduction.tex`. Can you describe the contents of these files?

Comment: @Mico here some of content in introduction.tex `\setstretch{2.0} \chapter{CHAPTER 1} %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{8}{INTRO‌​DUCTION}} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCTION} \section*{\rm \bf \hfill INTRODUCTION \hfill} \vspace{1cm} In this chapter, we will study a....`

Comment: @caca - And what about the `thesis` document class? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Mico i got the template from http://www.torsten-schoen.de/2013/05/howto-write-a-thesis-using-latex-part-2-getting-started-with-latex/  , then i change report to thesis. the template wrote, --> LaTeX Thesis Template defined by Torsten Schön, May 2013